# Let a and g be primitive roots modulo p (where p is an odd prime). Prove that ag is not a primitive root modulo p.

Tags: modules, primitive-roots

Let a and g be primitive roots modulo p (where p is an odd prime). Prove that ag is not a primitive root modulo p.

I stumbled upon this problem and was confused about how to solve it, could anyone explain?
Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  squares can't be primitive roots.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can tackle it!